# Android Eclipse Error on Build : scd_cmd_1 Error 127 android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

My projects were working just fine until I updated the SDK.  Now all of my projects are displaying the following error when I try to build.

make: *** [scd_cmd_1] Error 127

I have tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse.  Anyone know how to fix this?  I am running Eclipse on MacOSX.

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely remove the project from the workspace and then re-add it.  What a pain but it worked.